# Getting Google Keep shortcuts to work with Category Tabs

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, google-chrome-extensions, google-keep

Pressing `?` in [Google Keep](https://www.google.com/keep/) gives an overview of the shortcuts that can be used.

[image: Screenshot of Google Keep shortcuts]

However, after I have installed [Category Tabs for Google Keep](https://carlosjeurissen.com/category-tabs-for-google-keep), some shortcuts don't seem to work anymore. For instance, pressing `c` or `l` doesn't do anything, while `j` and `k` still work fine.

Is there a reason why a particular set of shortcuts stopped working, and is there a way around this?

Edit:

It appears that selecting a certain category also hides the `Add Note` text box. So it seems that google keep is now in some kind of "search results mode". The question stands: is there a way around this? I want to add notes while I am in a category.

Comment: Aside: What features does the "Category Tabs for Google Keep" extension(?) provide that the standard Google Keep does not? You can already filter by colour in the stock Google Keep.

Comment: I see. I guess it just provides these tab buttons then. Still, the shortcut problem remains when using the filter in stock Google Keep.

Comment: Ah yeah, I see the problem. It does seem to be a "search results mode". Selecting a colour just filters by that colour (there are other non-colour filters). Presumably you would want to add a note that is already in that category (ie. change to the appropriate colour). Normally, when you add a note it starts white and you specifically need to change the colour, so it might not be as simple as being able to access the "new note" shortcut. There doesn't appear to be a keyboard shortcut for clearing the filter either?

Comment: @w3dk I haven't found a shortcut yet to clear the search results and it is not listed among the `?`. That is not conclusive though, as I have found shortcuts which are not documented, like `o` which opens the current note for edit.

Comment: This seems to be an issue you should be bringing up with the developer of the extension.